# css selector equivalent of $(this)

Tags: css, selector, this

Is there an equivalent to the Jquery selector `$(this)` in CSS? Like this:

```
.widget h4 { background: black }
.widget:hover h4 { background: white }
```

In this case, if *any* of the `.widget` classed elements are hovered over, the child `h4` will change background color. I'm asking if there is a way *in CSS* to do this so that *only* the `h4` of the single hovered `.widget` with have a bg color change, not every element with class `.widget`. Yes, I have searched all over Google and found nothing that answers. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your existing code should do this already. If it does not, it means that the widgets are nested and you should carefully reword your question.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/hover-on-everything-but/

Comment: My code does exactly what I expect. I expect that any element with `.widget` class is hovered, the child `h4` changes. But it changes for _all_ `.widget` elements. Am I missing something?

Comment: for me it does not change for all elements, just the child of the hovered `.widget` element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tFkC3/ this is not what you're after?

Comment: I would bet that in the real code you have put a comma .widget:hover, h4 {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted code should do exactly as you describe you want it to behave:

**css:**

```
.widget h4 { background: red }
.widget:hover h4 { background: white }
```

**html:**

```
<div class="widget">
   <h4>Hover here</h4>
   <h3>This won't change</h3>
</div>

<div class="widget">
    <h4>Hover here</h4>
</div>
```

With that code, if you hover over either of the divs `.widget` it will only change the direct child `h4` and not the one in the other div.

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2VmA/)